# Can I use the same Access database for both x86 and x64 database engines?

Tags: microsoft-access, database

I have developed a small winforms application (x86 Target CPU) for some of my clients to store data.  It uses a Microsoft Access Database.  Up until now all of my clients have been using x86 software, but now some are gradually migrating to x64 environments.

Since the database tables were manually created in Access (x86 version),  If I change my target CPU to x64 (for the x64 machines), will the same database file be usable in an x64 version of my program with an x64 database engine installed?

Comment: Same Access database can be used by you would have to use the required 64-bit driver in order to do so

Comment: @Ramhound So in other words, the database file can be shared and can be used by a system running the x86 database engine and can also be used by a system running the x64 database engine.

Comment: If it currently can be shared concurrently then it can continue to be shared concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

I regularly share .Accdb files between 32-bit MS Access and 64-bit MS Access instances, each running on 64-bit Windows.

If you use ODBC to access external data sources, you need to use the appropriate driver for your version of Access: 32-bit ODBC driver for a 32-bit MS Access, even if the OS is 64-bit.  Since the ODBC driver is not part of the database it's there's no compatibility issue, just use the same data source name when configuring the ODBC Data Source on each system.